# Is there a constexpr in new standard C11 (not C++11) or planned in the future?

Tags: c, c11

In the new language standard C++11 is present the keyword **constexpr**.

Is there a **constexpr** in new standard C11 (not C++11) or planned in the future?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is not a `constexpr` or similar usage keyword in C11. As to if it is planned in the future, the answer is "I don't know".

C11 §6.6 *Constant expressions* gives the constrains on constant expression:

> Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call,
>   or comma operators, except when they are contained within a subexpression that is not
>   evaluated.

Comment: That's a pity. In C++14 **constexpr**-functions planned with minimal restrictions. Possible: for, if, switch/case, calls to function, any mathematical operands and expressions.